# What tree is this with reddish body?

Tags: identification, trees

I live in Pacific Northwest and this tree is in our backyard

[image]

Here is the photo of its leaves

[image]

Do you know what tree is it?

It doesn't look that nice. It's not evergreen and quite trashy in the winter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a Madrone (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbutus_menziesii); it is loved or despised in equal amounts, some would consider you are fortunate to have a mature specimen. Certainly a distinctive tree, see if the description of the Madrone coincides with your tree.

Comment: I doubt it as this one has no berries. Plus it is not evergreen. Leaves falling down are trashy. However the white flowers do look like it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbutus_menziesii#/media/File:PacificMadroneBlossom.jpg

Comment: Since it has flowers, these usually lead to fruits of some kind unless lacking suitable pollinator. It would be a helpful clue if you could describe any fruits found, or a closeup of the flowers.